# Build a percentage sequence based on a second column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, sequence

I have a dataframe like this:

```
measure <- rnorm(1:100, mean = 5, sd = 2)
year <- c(rep(2015,25),rep(2016,25),rep(2015,25),rep(2016,25))
individuals <- c(rep('a',50), rep('b',50))
df <- as.data.frame(measure, year, individuals)
```

I wish to add a column displaying the percentage of `nrow(df)` according to the column 'individuals'. That is, a column starting at 0 and ending at 100 when it reaches the last line where `df$individuals == 'a'` occurs. Then it should start over until `df$individuals == 'b'` occurs, etc.

I tried the following:

```
fun1 <- function(x) 100*cumsum(x) / sum(x)
df[, percent := fun1(1:nrow(df)), by = df$individuals]
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that I need to subset my dataframe by `individuals`, but I'm struggling to find where and how I should to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are all `factors`.  We just need

```
df <-  data.frame(measure, year, individuals)
```

instead of

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(measure, year, individuals))
```

In the above, code, it is first converting to a `matrix` (with `cbind`).  A `matrix` can hold only a single class.  As the 'individual' column is `character`, it converts the whole `matrix` to `character`, and when we do `as.data.frame` (with default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`) all of them `character` columns convert to `factor`.  So, instead start with the `data.frame` call.

---

In the `data.table` part of the code, it is not shown whether the data was not converted to `data.table` or not.  The `by` doesn't need `df$`.  Also, the argument to `fun1` should be `seq` of the groups i.e. `seq_len(.N)` instead of the whole number of rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, percent := fun1(seq_len(.N)), by = individuals]
head(df)
#    measure year individuals    percent
#1: 7.384682 2015           a 0.07843137
#2: 7.265650 2015           a 0.23529412
#3: 3.536816 2015           a 0.47058824
#4: 3.139754 2015           a 0.78431373
#5: 5.314709 2015           a 1.17647059
#6: 3.962159 2015           a 1.64705882
```

Comment: Any idea as for my original question though ?

Comment: @Y.Coch  I updated the solution.  I was thinking earlier that your initial code is problematic.  But, by looking at your second code, realized that there are some issues which I corrected

Comment: thank you it works in the example. In my original data, what I didn't mention is that there is a second column from which wanted  to build my sequence from.

using  `by = c(individuals, variable2)`  works. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Y.Coch Are you grouping by two columns or by only individuals.  If the second variable is the sequence,  the values should range from 1:row number where the group ends

Comment: by two columns (the second being in the same form than `individuals`. So in the end I get `percent` values ranging from 1 to 100 for each `interaction(individuals, variable2)`.

Comment: @YCoch  In that case just do `by = .(individuals, variable2)` and then use the same code

Comment: works like a charm, cheers ! So what's the difference between the dot and interaction ?

Comment: @Y.Coch `interaction` is similar to `paste` in concatenating the values but the output is a `factor`.  In the `by` we just need the column names instead of the values

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`

```
df$percent<-rep(0,nrow(df))
count<-0
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  if (df[i,3]==df[i-1,3] && i!=nrow(df)){
    df[i,4]<-df[i-1,4]+1
    count<-count+1
  }
  else{
    df[(i-1-count):(i-1),4]<-(df[(i-1-count):(i-1),4]/count)*100
    df[i,4]<-0
    count<-0
  }
}

df

`
               measure year individuals    percent
1     3.54298117531633 2015           a   0.000000
2     6.76276664091015 2015           a   2.040816
3       4.940303054949 2015           a   4.081633
4   -0.274215381055852 2015           a   6.122449
5     3.85424764010803 2015           a   8.163265

46    6.48749027822134 2016           a  91.836735
47    4.92015417666705 2016           a  93.877551
48    2.56157340714661 2016           a  95.918367
49     7.0784144318028 2016           a  97.959184
50    2.36113372724998 2016           a 100.000000
51    8.39095200078212 2015           b   0.000000
52    6.23553126520668 2015           b   2.083333
53    6.03842048180984 2015           b   4.166667
54    7.26653490675355 2015           b   6.250000
55    7.91569540359305 2015           b   8.333333
56    3.01962780509906 2015           b  10.416667
57    2.56912081318865 2015           b  12.500000
58    1.67522578937297 2015           b  14.583333
59    1.25065179768467 2015           b  16.666667
60    4.90863986735939 2015           b  18.750000
61    6.89995323457065 2015           b  20.833333

97     4.4984459215344 2016           b  95.833333
98    6.08384989789474 2016           b  97.916667
99     1.4026759075611 2016           b 100.000000
```